# Populate map values in field

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to populate values in field which is in map.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger AccountTrigger_AT on Account (before update,before insert) 
{

 AccountTrigger_ATHandler accountHandler = new AccountTrigger_ATHandler();

    set<String> accountIndustrySet = new set<String>();

    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Account getAccount : Trigger.new){
            if(getAccount.Industry != null){
               accountIndustrySet.add(getAccount.Industry);   
            }            
        }
        accountHandler.populateAccountNames(accountIndustrySet,Trigger.new,accountIn);
    }
}
```

**Trigger Handler Class:**

```
public class AccountTrigger_ATHandler {

    Map<String,String> accountIndustryMap = new Map<String,String>();
    public String AccountNames;

    public void populateAccountNames(Set<String> accountIndustrySet,List<Account> newAccountList,Map<String,String> accountIn){
            for(Account getAccountMap : [SELECT AccountNames__c,Name,Industry FROM Account WHERE Industry IN : accountIndustrySet]){
                accountIndustryMap.put(getAccountMap.Industry, getAccountMap.Name); 
        AccountNames = accountIndustryMap.get(getAccountMap.Industry);

            }

        for(Account newAccount : newAccountList){
            if(accountIndustryMap.containsKey(newAccount.Industry)){
                newAccount.AccountNames__c = AccountNames;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement? I request you to brief us about the objective of this code.Correct me if I am wrong but the way I see it, as soon as an Account is created which has value in industry field, you want to populate a custom field named "Account Names" with the names of Accounts who have the same Industry value in their "Industry" field right?

Comment: Yes Abhijeet you are correct.. Could you please help me for this requirement..

Comment: Sure....i will post my code (working ) in a while :)

Comment: happy to do so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your trigger handler code with the below one:

```
public class AccountTrigger_ATHandler {

    Map<String,String> accountIndustryMap = new Map<String,String>();
    public String AccountNames;

    public void populateAccountNames(Set<String> accountIndustrySet,List<Account> newAccountList,Map<String,String> accountIn){

            for(Account getAccountMap : [SELECT AccountNames__c,Name,Industry FROM Account WHERE Industry IN : accountIndustrySet]){

                if(accountIndustryMap.containsKey(getAccountMap.Industry)){

                String str = accountIndustryMap.get(getAccountMap.Industry) +','+getAccountMap.Name
                accountIndustryMap.put(getAccountMap.Industry, str); 
                }

            else
        accountIndustryMap.put(getAccountMap.Industry,getAccountMap.Name);

            }

        for(Account newAccount : newAccountList){
            if(accountIndustryMap.containsKey(newAccount.Industry)){
                newAccount.AccountNames__c = accountIndustryMap.get(newAccount.Industry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a re-coding of Abhijeet's answer with mainly coding style changes intended to make what is going on clearer. But coding style is always a matter of opinion...

I particularly found the variable naming confusing (especially `getAccountMap`) and the use of class fields instead of local variables. Also given that there are only a few lines of code involved so that the context is clear, short variable names make the structure of what is going on clearer.

```
public class AccountTrigger_ATHandler {

    public void populateAccountNames(
            Set<String> accountIndustrySet,
            List<Account> newAccountList
            ) {

        Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>();
        for(Account a : [
                select Name, Industry
                from Account
                where Industry in :accountIndustrySet
                order by Name
                ]) {
            String s = m.get(a.Industry);
            if (s != null) s = s + ', ' + a.Name;
            else s = a.Name;
            m.put(a.Industry, s);
        }

        for (Account a : newAccountList) {
            if (m.containsKey(a.Industry)) a.AccountNames__c = m.get(a.Industry);
        }
    }
}
```